# DataGridview with linq-to-sql

Tags: linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is used for listing all the students information .I am using linq to sql as a datasource.My problem arises when I edit a row or add a new row directly in a gridview.I mean there are no any forms for editing or adding student information.User should type on the particular columns to edit or to add a new row.
I found the soultions which uses SqlDataAdapter .

TableAdapter.Update(e.Row); which updates the database.

I wonder how can I achieve the same functionality using linq to sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `SubmitChanges()` method of the `DataContext`, which you used to fill the `DataGridView`.

MSDN reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292162.aspx

Comment: I would be more than happy If you could share the tutorial.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the most useful will be this(it's a sub page of the last linked): [How to: Submit Changes to the Database (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx)
Check the Manipulating Data Walkthrough: [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386927.aspx) [VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386924.aspx). And see also: [Making and Submitting Data Changes (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882674.aspx)